Connect to Snowflake from databricks azure unity catalog using a PEM key
I am using the databricks UI on azure to connect to Snowflake. We are trying to use the PEM key option but I get the following error

summary: IllegalArgumentException: Input PEM private key is invalid, data: {"type":"baseError","stackFrames":

We generally us the following command to generate keys and then encrypt them using a password but since databricks doesnt have an input filed for the password we generated the key without encryption.
openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -out privatekey.p8 -nocrypt
The UI calls for a PEM private key in HEX64.
I need help generating required HEX64 PEM private key and also generating the associated public key which will be added to the Snowflake user.
Thank you in advance!


Is you key is correct

as it expects in HEX64 format you need to encode it as base64 using base64 privatekey.p8 > privatekey_base64.pem command and try using this value in UI

Using the below you can generate the private and public keys:
openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -out privatekey.p8 -nocrypt
openssl rsa -in privatekey.p8 -pubout -out publickey.pem

The above will generate a private key in PKCS#8 format without encryption
privatekey.p8 The private key to be used in Databricks.
publickey.pem The public key to be added to the Snowflake user.
Once these Keys are genrated you can upload them to your databricks workspace.
You can load the keys in azure databricks and encode it in base64 HEX64 format for Snowflake authentication.
below is the code for loading the private key and formating the private key as HEX64:
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import re
with open("/dbfs/FileStore/privatekey.p8", "rb") as key_file:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
private_key_pem = private_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
).decode("utf-8")
private_key_hex64 = re.sub(r"-----.*-----|\n", "", private_key_pem)
print(private_key_hex64)

Snowflake Connection with Databricks:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("SnowflakeConnection") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/dbfs/FileStore/jars/snowflake-jdbc.jar,/dbfs/FileStore/jars/spark-snowflake.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
sfOptions = {
    "sfURL": "<snowflake account url>",  
    "sfAccount": "<account>",
    "sfUser": "<username>",
    "sfWarehouse": "<warehouse>",
    "sfDatabase": "<database>",
    "sfSchema": "<schema>",
    "pem_private_key": private_key_hex64  
}
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
df = spark.read.format(CSV) \
    .options(**sfOptions) \
    .option("query", "SELECT * FROM <TABLE>") \
    .load()
df.show()

Reference: Pyspark: Error Connecting to Snowflake using Private Key
